# Python. Работа со строками

Tags: python, строки

Есть текст (не обращайте внимание на смысл предложений). **"Сегодня чудесный день.Зачем ты испортил эту рубашку?Когда-то я куплю ручку, и тогда всё изменится.Где находится тот кабинет?Очень интересный вопрос.Холодно.Ты будешь заботиться о котёнке, пока меня не будет?"** Нужно написать программу, которая будет определять сколько вопросительных предложений в этом тексте, и сколько слов в каждом вопросительном предложении. В этом тексте вопросительных предложений 3. В первом *вопросительном* предложении *5 слов*, во втором - *4 слова*.

Comment: Ну напишите, раз нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала можно разделить текст на предложения, воспользовавшись поиском по следующему регулярному выражению: `.*?[.?]`.

Затем отфильтровать предложения, в качестве условия проверяя наличие символа `?` в конце.

Количество предложений будет равно длине получившегося списка.

Для получения количества слов, требуется разделить предложение по пробелам и так же, как с предложениями, найти длину списка.

***Пример:***

```py
import re


def main():
    text = "Сегодня чудесный день.Зачем ты испортил эту рубашку?Когда-то я куплю ручку, и тогда всё изменится.Где находится тот кабинет?Очень интересный вопрос.Холодно.Ты будешь заботиться о котёнке, пока меня не будет?"

    sentences = re.findall('.*?[.?]', text)
    questions = list(filter(lambda s: s.endswith('?'), sentences))
    questions_count = len(questions)
    words_counts = [len(s.split()) for s in questions]

    print(questions_count)
    print(*words_counts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
3
5 4 9
```